# How to find out nearest high contrast color which override the background color for better QR scannability?

Tags: javascript, colors, qr-code

QRcode image

[image]

In this Qrcode image, the background color is almost the same as eye/data color means the contrast level is very low so it is difficult or unable to scan the QR. I am using this library [npm contrast color calc](https://github.com/nico-hn/color-contrast-calc) to find the nearest contrast color,

```js
let eyeCol = ColorContrastCalc.colorFrom('#535050');
let backgroundCol = ColorContrastCalc.colorFrom('#67696b');
if(eyeCol && backgroundCol){
  if(eyeCol.contrastRatioAgainst(backgroundCol) <3){
    
    let aaContrast1 = eye_Color.findLightnessThreshold(background_Color, 'AA');
    return aaContrast1;
  }
}

///////output: '#54C571' //////////
```

Output color coming from this code is far from the given color.
But I want to restrict users to select the background color which might overlap with the eye color or foreground color. If user select same color for both (let say for eye and background) then it has to return the nearest high contrast color for background, so it will become easier for the scanners to differentiate the foreground from the background.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) It's just an SO thing, but I'd suggest rewording the question to just ask how to find the nearest high-contrast color, rather than asking for a library (which is specifically off-topic here). People will tend to vote to close.

Comment: *"I am using this library https://github.com/nico-hn/color-contrast-calc to find the nearest contrast color by `let aaContrast1 = eye_Color.findLightnessThreshold(background_Color, 'AA'); let aaContrast2 = eye_Color.findBrightnessThreshold(background_Color, 'AA');`"* Are you having a problem with that? Is it not working? In what way?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Let's say if a user selects red color as the foreground color. Now if user selects the same color or any color close to it as background color, the foreground may overlap with the background and it will become difficult for the scanners to differentiate the foreground from the background. I want to restrict users to select the background color which might overlap with the foreground color and return the nearest high contrast color.  I have updated the query, have a look

Answer (score 0):

depending on the final output type, screen/print/download, you could use...

- css filter grayscale() and contrast()
- does the QR code generator library have config parameters for color or size?
- https://www.w3.org/2013/chroma/